# Can I use concurrency.ProcessPoolExecutor as a long lived object?

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency, multiprocessing

I have some asynchronous code that works with the network and from time to time (for instance, every 10 seconds) requests and receives data that needs to be parsed in some way (an explicit CPU-bound task).

Doing this on the main thread (and even a process, due to the GIL) is not recommended even in the [asyncio documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#running-blocking-code).
Is it a good idea (and is it possible) to create a long lived object like [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) to handle these tasks?

Will there be any downside effects when using this object, such as the processes will be initialized each time anew?

Am I trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes you can. You just need to initialize the processes once they won't be created again and again for the tasks you submit. Make sure you explicitly submit the process pool to `loop.run_in_executor` and that the process pool itself persists between calls

Comment: @Charchit Thanks! Is it right that I can use this pool only in the main thread and loop?

Comment: I don't see any reason you cannot use it in any other thread or loop, best to test it.